# Font Awesome stopped showing icons, shows &# text instead

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

after migrating my WP site to a different domain and making adjustments, Font Awesome stopped showing icons and shows some weird text instead, for example & # 61505; (I can't copy it as a text, looks like an automatically generated graphics).

Please see attached image.
[image]

Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: It is very probably that font files are not loaded. Can you check it?

Comment: How are you importing Fontawesome? Through the CDN? Downloaded filesheet? Or with the embed code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Check following thing into your site

Please check that Font Awesome **CSS** is l**oading into page** , you can check it using view page source, also need to check **fonts folder** is uploaded into all your sites , if you not upload fonts folder then it don't display icon.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Font Awesome styles are already included in the css of the template so icons should work. It was working properly in the site before migration, you can check here: http://irfc2017.com/ After migration to different page (not public yet), icons appeared correctly but suddenly they stopped showing up.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was in copying theme's css file from an old to a new site. The "fa" icons changed from a graphical to a textual form in the css style. Thanks for help.